# Timing a Recursive Function using Decorators

Tags: python, recursion, python-decorators

I am trying to make a timer decorator that times a function with variously sized lists. The timer works for insert(), which I have written below, but not for a recursive function such as minimum(). I get a recursion depth error for any list that has size greater than 1. How should I remedy this?

```
def time_long_list(func):
    import random
    def helper(*args, **kwargs):
        for item in [10, 100, 1000, 10000]:
            list = [random.randint(1, 10) for element in range(item)]
            with Timer() as clock:
                func(list)
            print(clock.interval/item)
        return func
    return helper

@time_long_list
def insert(lst):
    new_list = []
    for item in lst:
        new_list.insert(0, item)
    return new_list

@time_long_list
def minimum(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return None
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    else:
        mid = len(lst) // 2
        min1 = minimum(lst[:mid])
        min2 = minimum(lst[mid:])
        if min1 <= min2:
            return min1
        else:
            return min2

insert()
minimum()
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to make this a decorator. You lose access to the original function, which is especially terrible when the original function needs access to itself.

Comment: So should I just define a new function variable mini = time_long_list(minimum)?

Comment: That'd work. Alternatively, `time_long_list` could just directly time the function it's passed instead of generating a timing wrapper.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a decorator. But if you use it on a recursive function, you probably want to decorate a wrapper function (that is, unless you're interested in sub-timings).

Comment: I've seen memoization decorators for recursive functions such as the fibonacci function. These do not raise any recursive depth error unless the number called is around 1000, whereas my timer decorator failed for list size >= 2 when decorating the minimum function. What is the difference between these two cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you decorate a function, you are telling the python interpreter to take the function, do 'some stuff' to it, and then store a reference to the new, modified function in the global / module namespace.

By definition, recursion is a function calling itself.

So what you're trying to do here can't work, because your function is now decorated with all the code to generate test data. When you call the function recursively, you're generating all that test data every time. As new test data is being generated at every step, you can never get to the bottom of the recursion, and inevitably - you hit the depth limit.

What you need is to keep a reference to the original function when we decorate the function. You will then have two functions, one that generates the test data and performs the top level of the recursion, and another that doesn't generate test data. It's not quite pure recursion - as you have two functions not one, but it's probably the best you can do.

By modifying the decorator, we can keep a reference to the original function

```
def time_long_list(func):
    import random
    def helper(*args, **kwargs):
        for item in [10, 100, 1000, 10000]:
            list = [random.randint(1, 10) for element in range(item)]
            with Timer() as clock:
                func(list, func)
                print(clock.interval/item)
        return func
    helper.original = func
return helper
```

Then modifying your recursive function so that it always calls the original version of itself, not the modified version

```
@time_long_list
def minimum(lst, undecorated_func = None):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return None
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    else:
        mid = len(lst) // 2
        min1 = minimum.original(lst[:mid])
        min2 = minimum.original(lst[mid:])
        if min1 <= min2:
            return min1
        else:
            return min2
```

I don't suggest that this is a good way to do this - you would be better off - as the comments suggest, creating a seperate top level function to do the timing and test data creation if possible.